# Consolidate List<T> with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm just wondering if there is a way to consolidate a List of order objects with linq? My scenario is the following which i've condensed down for the purpose of this question.

```
public class Order
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}
```

This would become a List based on the above as follows:

```
GUID       PARENT       ID         Desc          Qty           Total
====================================================================
aaa                     120        Burger         1            2.50
bbb        aaa          121        + Bacon        1            0.50
ccc                     123        Fries          1            1.50
ddd                     120        Burger         1            2.50
eee        ddd          124        + Cheese       1            0.30
fff                     123        Fries          1            1.50
```

what i would like to do in this example is to end up with the following

```
GUID       PARENT       ID         Desc          Qty           Total
====================================================================
aaa                     120        Burger         1            2.50
bbb        aaa          121        + Bacon        1            0.50
ccc                     123        Fries          2            3.00
ddd                     120        Burger         1            2.50
eee        ddd          124        + Cheese       1            0.30
```

where i don't try to consolidate if the item has a child product and essentially sum to totals and quantities for everything else.

My thinking at the minute is to create a separate list of only products with no children sum this, and to an elaborate merge with products which do have children.

I can do it this way but i'm wondering if there is a cleaner approach, any input would be greatly appreaciated

Comment: Looking for Concat? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: why aren't you adding the quantities when you add an item? Check first to see if the item is already in that list and if so add +1 to the quantity..

Comment: I agree with @Spluf - this isn't the best schema for your data. That's not an order - it's an order *item*. The list is the order, but it sounds like it doesn't provide an interface giving you the data you want.

Comment: Assuming the GUID is unique to each item type, you might do better by keeping a `Dictionary<GUID, count>` as your order instead. Better yet - wrap the dictionary and provide nice, named methods - AddItem, GetItemCount, ...

Comment: @spluf in an ideal world thats what i would do only i'm constrained by a third party application which i've no control over unfortunately

Comment: @JazziJeff hooraaaaay -_-

Answer (score 3):

This should keep orders with children separate, and consolidate only stand-alone orders:

```
var orders = originalOrders.GroupBy(_ => _.parent ? _.parent : _.guid);
var consolidated = orders
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1) // only orders with no children
    .SelectMany(grp => grp)
    .GroupBy(_ => _.ID)
    .Select(grp => grp.Aggregate((a,b) => new order
        {
            guid = a.guid,
            parent = a.parent,
            ProductID = a.ProductID,
            Description = a.Description,
            Quantity = a.Quantity + b.Quantity,
            Total = a.Total + b.Total
        }
));

var allOrders = orders
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp)
    .Concat(consolidated);
```

Comment: This looks ok, but I think you miss one condition : `don't try to consolidate if the item has a child product`

Comment: Ooops yes good point! The OP should decide how to handle this situation, for example should a burger with bacon and a burger with cheese be displayed as 2x burger, 1 bacon, 1 cheese? It would be helpful to have a reference to the children on the order class

Comment: I would not consolidate it as 2xburger 1 bacon 1 cheese because with that its hard to know which one has what or doe one burger have both - thats the reason behind not consolidating anything with a child product - complicated i know!

Comment: @JazziJeff I've edited my answer to keep orders with children separate

Comment: Hi Mike - sorry i'm only getting back to this now - your line var orders = originalOrders.GroupBy(_ => _.parent ? _.parent : _.guid); give me a cannot implicitly convert type string to bool error on compilation any suggestions? see https://dotnetfiddle.net/FyIfZV

Comment: The idea is to have the parent guid if there is one, and if not have the orders own guid, so for example if the orders with no parent have `parent == null` then you can do `_ => _.parent == null ? _.guid : _.parent`, or if it is an empty string you can do: `_ => string.IsNullOrEmpty(_.parent) ? _.guid : _.parent`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - i sussed that out and implemented string.isnullorempty but again ran into difficulty with the second select many with the type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage - the link above in my comment has been updated to show this

Comment: Sorry! Yes that sohuld be a `Select` not a `SelectMany`, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in one go the key is to calculate something to group on.
Since we don't want to group items with children we need something unique for those items to group on. If we take the two burger rows the only thing that is different on them is the Guid so this needs to be in our grouping. If the item have no child rows we should group them.
So we calculate a group clause that becomes the Guid if the item has children and an empty string if the item have no children.
Then ProductID need to be grouped on as well because this is what we want to group items without children on.

```
var lst = orders.GroupBy(x => new
{
    x.ProductID,
    GuidIfHaveChildren = (orders.Any(x2 => x2.Parent == x.Guid) ? x.Guid : ""),
    x.parent
}).Select(x => new
 {
     Guid = x.First().Guid,
     Parent = x.First().Parent,
     Id = x.Key.ProductID,
     Desc = x.First().Description,
     Qty = x.Sum(p => p.Quantity),
     Total = x.Sum(p => p.Total)
 });
```

Comment: very close but it seems to group the child products against the parent. for example if i sell 1x burger +bacon, 2x fries, 1x burger plus bacon the output is 1x burger + 2xbacon,2xfries, 1x burger - ideally it should keep the bacon with each burger if that makes sense

Comment: Could you update the example data to include such a case? So i get it right.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S6WhNW - a quick fiddle here with your answer just for testing, thanks

Comment: thats perfect, i'm just testing some edge cases now but great stuff

Answer (score 1):

```
from o in orders
group o by o.ID into g
from gg in g select new Order
{
        guid = gg.guid, parent = gg.parent, ProductId = gg.ProductId, Description = gg.Description,
        Quantity = orders.Any(od=> od.parent != null || od.parent == gg.guid) 
                        ? gg.Quantity : g.Sum(ggg=>ggg.Quantity),
        Total = orders.Any(od=> od.parent != null || od.parent == gg.guid) 
                        ? gg.Total : g.Sum(ggg=>ggg.Total)
}
```

There might be some performance issue with this, but this should get you started.

Comment: thanks, i seem to run into an issue around from gg in select new Order see https://dotnetfiddle.net/S6WhNW if you get a chance